# save for xml path to file

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I'm tring to save xml result to file in sql server 2008.
I need this process to happen automatically on each insert/update/delete
so I'm trying to do it directly in sql management studio via triggers.
I followed this solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8d9247e-e6c3-4b70-9b2d-943a863e665b/send-results-of-select-for-xml-query-to-a-file?forum=transactsql

but unfortunately, I keep getting this error when I try to execute:
    "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.outputxml'."

what is the problem?

I can see the dll and the stored procedure I've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For future similar questions:

The command should be:

EXEC **dbo.output** @output, 'c:\Output.xml'

and not

EXEC dbo.outputxml @output, 'c:\Output.xml'